# java.time.DateTimeException: Invalid value for Year (valid values -999999999 - 999999999)

Tags: java, java-8, epoch, localdate

I am getting this exception when I am trying to convert epochTime to LocalDate where:

1) Date : 2017-05-05 10:08:52.0

2) corresponding epoch :1493959132000

```
LocalDate lastUpdatedDate = LocalDate.ofEpochDay(1493959132000);
```

Exception :

```
java.time.DateTimeException: Invalid value for Year (valid values -999999999 - 999999999): 4090323145
    at java.time.temporal.ValueRange.checkValidIntValue(ValueRange.java:330)
    at java.time.temporal.ChronoField.checkValidIntValue(ChronoField.java:722)
    at java.time.LocalDate.ofEpochDay(LocalDate.java:341)
```

I understand that the sourcecode of java.time.LocalDate gives a prior warning of this exception at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#ofEpochDay-long-

What does this actually mean and when does it come?

Comment: Well, 1493959132000 days, is roughly 1493959132000/365=4,093,000,000 years as stated in the exception message. Your assumptions are wrong. 4,000,000,000+epochYear > 2017. Epoch year is 1970, so (2017-1970)*365 almost equals to 17500 days...

Comment: Once again, reading the javadoc of the method you're calling would help a lot. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#ofEpochDay-long-

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Here's](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#ofEpochDay-long-) javadoc of `ofEpochDay`, this is what it says:

> This returns a LocalDate with the specified epoch-day. The EPOCH_DAY
>   is a simple incrementing count of days where day 0 is 1970-01-01.
>   Negative numbers represent earlier days.

So, it expects the argument to be number of days since `1970-01-01`. As the value you are passing is not valid, it throws the `Exception`.

Now, coming to your use case, if you want to convert epoch time to localdate then you need to use `ofEpochMilli` method of `Instant` class, e.g.:

```
LocalDate localDate =
        Instant.ofEpochMilli(1493959132000l).atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();
System.out.println(localDate);
```

[Here's](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) javadoc for `Instant` class.

**Update**

Alternatively, you can convert the timestamp into number of days since 1970-01-01 and pass it to `ofEpochDay()` method, e.g.:

```
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.ofEpochDay(1493959132000l/(1000 * 60 *60 * 24));
System.out.println(localDate);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you think about it, it doesn't make sense convert epoch **seconds** to local dates. At a specific moment in time you still need a location/time zone to determine which side of the date demarcation line you're on.

The epoch you mention is Fri, 05 May 2017 04:38:52 UTC. If you're in Greenwhich the LocalDate would be May 5th but if you're on the US West Coast it's still May 4th. Here's a [list converting that epoch to different time zones](https://www.epochconverter.com/timezones?q=1493959132)

```
Instant.ofEpochMilli(1493959132000L).atZone(ZoneOffset.UTC).toLocalDate() //2017-05-05
Instant.ofEpochMilli(1493959132000L).atZone(ZoneId.of("America/Chicago")).toLocalDate() //2017-05-04
```

Therefore the argument asks for the amount of epoch **days** to convert to a local date.

```
LocalDate.ofEpochDay(17291) //2017-05-05
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the timeInMillis as the value instead of number of days. You could use the Duration class to calculate the number of days.

```
Duration duration = Duration.ofMillis(1493959132000);
long days = duration.toDays();
LocalDate lastUpdatedDate = LocalDate.ofEpochDay(days);
```